# How to find serial number of my paired Airpods through my mac (not iPhone)

Tags: mac, bluetooth, airpods

How to find serial number of my paired Airpods through my mac (not iPhone)

I lost my Airpods while attempting to send it to Apple for repair. They are asking for the serial number, the last thread I have is that it was previously paired on my mac. Is there a way I can find the serial number of my lost Airpods?

Answer (score -1):

If you’ve ever had them paired with your iPhone try going to Settings/Bluetooth and then pressing the blue i on the right hand side, the serial number shown is for the airpod case but if you tap that number it will then display the left then right airpod numbers.

Comment: The OP specifically asks to find the serial "through my mac (not iPhone)".

Comment: Although the OP does say through his Mac he may be unaware that an iPhone will still show the serial numbers of previously paired AirPods whether they are connected or not, as he was asking of ways to trace the serial numbers of his missing AirPods it may be worth a try, but thankss for pointing it out Agarza.. Have you a better idea??

Comment: i guess i could have made it even more clear. unfortunately it's not paired with my iphone anymore. My mac is my only option